# Social security number in the mutual fund account page

Tags: united-states, mutual-funds

I have a social security number that I'm not sure if it is mine or not. I've been given this SSN from my parents long time ago and I need to verify it.

This number however, matches the number showed in my mutual fund account in the US that has been opened for decades.
So my question would be do they (the mutual fund broker/company) check and validate my SSN that it matches my name or not?

Added background info from another question:

I'm a dual citizen with US and another citizen in another country. I was born outside the US but because one of my parents is an american, I was given a US citizenship also apart from my local one. I've studied, worked and lived outside the US in the past 35 years. the latest visit to the US soil was about six years ago for less than a month stay (touring). All my registrations with schools, universities, banks, brokers ... the company that I work for are registered as a local citizen (no one knows I also have a US passport)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can validate your Social Security number at http://www.ssa.gov/employer/ssnv.htm

Your mutual fund is not an appropriate way to check the validity of your SSN. The issuing organization is the best place to go; in this case that is the Social Security Administration within US government.

Comment: Ditto. I would not rely on the SSN on paperwork for a mutual fund. Personally I don't know if there's any law or other requirement for them to check the social security number that you or your parents put on a form. But even if there was, maybe they got careless and didn't do it or made a mistake. I wouldn't stake my own future on just assuming that someone else did his job right.

Answer (score 0):

As a US citizen, you are legally required to file tax returns each year, even if you do not live in the U.S. and even if you earn no money in the U.S.

Your tax returns will have your SSN on them, and the IRS will check the validity as part of the filing process.

Comment: Sorry, I saw in another question that you have not been filing tax returns. As such, this answer doesn't apply to you but may plausibly be helpful to others.

Comment: You do not have to file a tax return if you earned no income. See the instructions for IRS form 1040 or 1040A. You do not have to file if you are single and earned less than $10,000, or if you are married filing jointly and earned less than $20,000. (Other numbers for other situations, and the limits are a little higher if you are over 65.)

Comment: Yeah, but note that's income anywhere in the world, not income solely in the U.S. There are other criteria which may require that you file; see http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Do-You-Need-to-File-a-Federal-Income-Tax-Return%3F